# If $p\in\Bbb Z[X]$ show that: $ \max\limits_{x\in [0,1]}\left|p(x) \right| > \frac{1}{e^{n}}. $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory, analysis, contest-math

This is problem 10 from the International Mathematical Competition for University Students of 2015, from day 2, in Bulgaria. I think it is an interesting problem!

> Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with integer coefficients. Prove that
>   $$
> \max_{x\in [0,1]}\left|p(x) \right| > \frac{1}{e^{n}}.
> $$

Proposed by Géza Kós, Eötvös University, Budapest.

Comment: Here is a solution found on Math Links: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1122156_imc2015_problem_10

Comment: Shouldn't the AoPS link be added as a answer?

Comment: See participants' scores [here](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2015/imc2015-scores.html). No one got more than 4 out of 10 for this problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $ M = \max_{x\in [0,1]}\left|p(x) \right| $ we know that

$$ M = \max_{x\in [0,1]}\left|p(x)\right| =\lim_{j\to \infty}\left(\int_0^1 \left|p(x)\right|^j dx\right)^{\frac{1}{j}}=\lim_{j\to \infty}\left(\int_0^1 \left|p(x)\right|^{2j} dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2j}}$$

We then consider
$$ M_{j} =\int_0^1 \left|p(x)\right|^{2j} dx$$

> since $\deg p= n$ then it follows that , $\deg p^{2j}= 2jn$. so, If we Can write it as, 
>   $$p^{2j}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{2jn} a_{j,k}x^k$$

Therefore, 
$$ M_{j} =\int_0^1 \left|p(x)\right|^{2j} dx \ge\left|\int_0^1 p(x)^{2j} dx \right| = \left|\sum_{k=0}^{2jn} \frac{a_{j,k}}{i+1}\right|$$
Let $\color{blue}{\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\cdots,  2jn+1)}$ be **the least common factor** of $(1,2,3,\cdots,  2jn)$. Then since $a_{k,i}\in \Bbb Z$ we have,

$$ M_{j}\ge \left|\sum_{k=0}^{2jn} \frac{a_{j,k}}{i+1}\right|\ge \frac{1}{lcm(1,2,3,\cdots,  2jn+1)}$$
[We get from this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217845/asymptotics-of-the-least-common-multiple-of-the-first-natural-numbers) that, 
$$\color{red}{\log (\color{blue}{\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\cdots,  2jn+1)})\sim 2jn+1}$$

hence for $\varepsilon>0$ and for $j$  large enough we have,

$$\color{blue}{\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\cdots,  2jn+1)}\le \exp((1+\varepsilon)(2jn+1) ) $$
which implies that

$$ \left(\int_0^1 \left|p(x)\right|^{2j} dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2j}} = M_j^{1/2j} \ge \left(\frac{1}{\color{blue}{\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\cdots,  2jn+1)}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2j}} \ge \frac{1}{\exp((1+\varepsilon)(n+\frac{1}{2j}) ) }$$

Taking $j\to \infty$ we get

$$ M = \max_{x\in [0,1]}\left|p(x)\right| = \lim_{j\to \infty}\left(\int_0^1 \left|p(x)\right|^{2j} dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2j}} \ge \frac{1}{\exp((1+\varepsilon)n ) }~~~\forall ~~\varepsilon>0$$

That is $$ \color{blue}{M = \max_{x\in [0,1]}\left|p(x)\right| \ge \frac{1}{e^n }}$$

Comment: Why ? How can that be possible I don't see . please clarify

Comment: You need a $\geqslant$ rather than a $=$ there at the end. $M = f(\varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ doesn't make sense unless $f$ is constant. Besides, it's the limit as $j \to \infty$, not $n$.

Comment: ::))) I see it is just typo your  right. I taught It is a huge mistake

Comment: @GuyFsone Very interesting solution! Is it possible to prove $lcm(1,\ldots,2jn) \leq \exp((1+\varepsilon)2nj)$ without appealing to the prime number theorem?

Comment: Honestly I am not an expert in number theory but I just find that in mathoverflow. It could be nice question in math stark exchange. that was gift. but here we have this result in more general set up: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496226/how-to-prove-that-int-01-log-px-dx-ge-n. I hope it will be reopen. I just updated it.

Comment: @Jack. is it ok now . if not then I am not getting your point so far

Comment: Sorry, it is "second last" in my first comment: $$ M = \max_{x\in [0,1]}\left|p(x)\right| = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\int_0^1 \left|p(x)\right|^{2j} dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2j}} \ge \frac{1}{\exp((1+\varepsilon)n ) }~~~\forall ~~\varepsilon>0$$

Comment: Yes I got that. But I want know if there is still a problem? with this part?

Comment: I saw it . It the same mistake in the first line. I just copied and pasted. Now it is ok. thank for correcting

Comment: Can't we use $M_j\triangleq\int_0^1|p(x)|^jdx$?

Answer (score 3):

I have to remark that the given inequality is fairly simple to prove if we replace $e$ with $4$.
Since the shifted Legendre polynomials provide an orthogonal base of $L^2(0,1)$ with respect to the standard inner product, we have
$$ \min_{\deg q<n}\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^n+q(x)\right)^2\,dx = \frac{1}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}^2} $$
hence $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\deg p=n$ imply
$$ \max_{x\in[0,1]}\left| p(x) \right| \geq \frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}\sqrt{2n+1}} >\frac{1}{4^n}.$$

Comment: Am I missing something, or does your inequality on $ \max_{x\in[0,1]}\left| p(x) \right|$ hold only when $p$ is monic of degree $n$ ? Not for all $p$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: if $p$ is not monic, then $\max|p(x)|$ is bounded below by $\frac{C}{4^n}$ where $C$ is the absolute value of the leading (integer) coefficient.

Comment: Ah yes, and $|C| \geq 1$ because $C$ is an integer. I see

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer, but adding to Colm's answer, we begin by noting that if the condition is being violated for any polynomial P(x), P(0) must be zero as must be P(1).

This is because both P(0) and P(1) are necessarily integral and will always exceed e^(-n) where n is as defined.

Hence, such a polynomial will always be expressible as x(x-1)g(x). By induction, we see that if |g(x)| reaches its maxima in a range lying in [1/2-k,1/2+k] such that the value of k allows x(x-1) to exceed e^(-2) in absolute value, we will have our contradiction and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Not a full answer** Just a (fairly obvious) idea for tackling this.

The case for $n = 1$ is just short of trivial. Let the polynomial be $ax + b$. Then if $|b| > \frac{1}{e}$, we can choose $x = 0$ and we're done. Else $|b| \leq \frac{1}{e}$. So choosing $x = 1$ we get $|ax + b| = |a + b| > 1 - \frac{1}{e} > \frac{1}{e}$. The last inequality chain holds because $a$ must be an  integer.

**Idea from here:** Induction on $n$. The inductive hypothesis gives us two results:

- The "sub-polynomial" of degree $n - 1$ reaches a value greater than $\frac{1}{e^{n - 1}}$ at some stage
- The derivative, which is of degree $n - 1$ reaches a value greater than $\frac{1}{e^{n - 1}}$ at some stage.

Maybe also the Taylor series expansion for $e^{-nx}$ would be useful here, because then we're comparing polynomials with polynomials.