# Let $p\in\Bbb Z[X]$ then prove that: $ \int_0^1 \log |p(x)| dx\ge -n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$. Prove that
$$ \int_0^1 \log |p(x)| dx \ge -n$$
This [If $p\in\Bbb Z_n[X]$ show that: $ \max\limits_{x\in [0,1]}\left|p(x) \right| > \frac{1}{e^{n}}. $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379195/imc-2015-problem-10-)
 becomes now a consequence of the current problem.

**Now this problem is completely different from the other one.**
and the other is just a consequence of this one.

Comment: "integer coefficients" means $\mathbb Z$, right ?

Comment: @GuyFsone For me, it was clear as it was before editing.

Comment: If $p(i)\neq 0$ for $i=0$ or $i=1$, then $|p(i)| \geq 1 \geq e^{-n}$. So you may assume $p(0)=p(1)=0$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers  Yes you are right I meant a polynomial of degree n with  coeffienct in $\Bbb Z$