# What is the minimal possible value of ${\max_{x\in [0,1]}} |f(x)|$ if $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is of degree $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials

Following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379195/if-p-in-bbb-zx-show-that-max-limits-x-in-0-1-leftpx-right-fr) that asks to show that $\displaystyle{\max_{x\in [0,1]}} |f(x)| > \dfrac{1}{{\rm e}^n}$ for every $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $n$, I am curious about the actual minimal value that $\displaystyle{\max_{x\in [0,1]}} |f(x)|$ can take.

Let's write $S = \displaystyle{\max_{x\in [0,1]}} |f(x)|$.

$\deg f = 1$: $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$ at the same time is impossible, otherwise $f(x)$ would be divisible by $x(x-1)$. So $S\ge \max\{|f(0)|,|f(1)|\}\ge 1$. $S=1$ can be achieved by $f(x) = \pm x,\pm (x-1), \pm (2x-1)$.

$\deg f = 2$: If $f(0)\neq 0$ or $f(1)\neq 0$, then $S\ge 1$. If $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, then $f(x) = ax(x-1)$, and we can see that the minimal possible value of $S$ is $\dfrac{1}{4}$, achieved by $f(x) = \pm x(x-1)$.

$\deg f = 3$: If $f(0)\neq 0$ or $f(1)\neq 0$, then $S\ge 1$. If $f\Big(\dfrac{1}{2}\Big)\neq 0$, then $S\ge \dfrac{1}{8}$. If $f(0) = f(1) = f\Big(\dfrac{1}{2}\Big) = 0$, then $f(x) = ax(x-1)(2x-1)$, and we can see that the minimal possible value of $S$ is $\dfrac{1}{6\sqrt{3}}$, achieved by $f(x) = \pm x(x-1)(2x-1)$.

$\deg f = 4$: I guess that $S_\min = \dfrac{1}{16}$, achieved by $f(x) = \pm x^2(x-1)^2, \pm x(x-1)(2x-1)^2$?

My argument for $\deg f=1,2,3$ cannot proceed to $\deg f\ge 4$. So is there any result about the minimum of $S$ in the general case?

Comment: The cited question was already a hard question, it wanted only a rough estimate for the minimal value of $|f|$ for a polynomial $f\in\Bbb Z[x]$ taken on some fixed interval of length one. In the above question we have only some computation in the simplest cases, even the case $n=4$ is not fully completed. But the question seems to be related to the general case. Please state one and only one question per post. The answer "No" to the question in the general case should be mot-a-mot a valid answer. Please make clear which is the question.

Comment: @dan_fulea I've edited the wording. My question concerns the general case.

Comment: Just a side note that this question is related to questions involving [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Roots_and_extrema).